# Strange #REF! error in my sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, ref

I have an unusual case with Excel and `#REF!` error. I've this formula:

```
=INDEX($N$621:$WO$621;SMALL($N626:$WO626;2);0)
```

which gives me sometimes a proper value and sometimes gives me a `#REF!` error as a result. Link [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/156665217/Przechwytywanie.PNG).

I checked all my cells and everything is in its place.

I'm posting this [Excel sheet](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/156665217/ISWD.xlsx). The reference error occurs in column L, at 626 row and below.

Comment: Can you explain in words what you want the formula to do?

Comment: I want to find in $N626:$WO626 row a smallest value and use index function to find a corresponding value from $N$621:$WO$621 row (marked as light red) and put it as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula will fail whenever the SMALL function returns a number that is not 0 (all rows in $N$621:$WO$621) or 1 (the first row in $N$621:$WO$621), because $N$621:$WO$621 only contains 1 row.

Did you mean to use the result of the SMALL as the column index?

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant use the result of the SMALL as the column index.

Comment: But now this formula will display always value "2" which is what shouldn't happened.